# Hook priority in admin with custom plugin

Tags: hooks

As mentioned [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) admin_init is the first hook triggered when access wordpress dashboard.

But when I test it I found `tgmpa_register` triggers first

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sr_admin_init' );
add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'sr_register_required_plugins' );

function sr_admin_init(){
   // I NEED THIS TO TRIGGER FIRST
    wp_die("sr_admin_init");
}

function sr_register_required_plugins(){
   // this triggers first
    wp_die("sr_register_required_plugins");
}
```

Action hooks triggers:

1. tgmpa_register
2. admin_init: defines some variable like `$GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']`

I have a complicated case, but in general I need to use variable `$GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']` in `sr_register_required_plugins`. But it is not working because `tgmpa_register` triggers first.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The codex entry you site is simply **wrong**!  There are a lot of hooks fired before `admin_init` during admin requests, not least of which is `init`, which a lot of plugins use to do their initialization.

In particular, the [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com) plugin hooks into `init` (with the default priority = 10) with a function that calls `do_action ('tgmpa_register')`.

Hence, you'll need to do something like:

```
// make sure we register this hook func with lower priority value than 
// TGM Plugin Activation does
add_action ('init', 'sr_admin_init', 9) ;

function
sr_admin_init ()
{
    if (!is_admin ()) {
        return ;
        }

    // I NEED THIS TO TRIGGER FIRST
    wp_die("sr_admin_init");
}
```

**Edit**

To be more charitable to the author of the codex entry you site: `admin_init` **is** the 1st "strictly admin"-related hook fired for admin requests.  It's just not the 1st hook fired.